# What is equivalent of "displacement" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

All dictionaries translate "discplacement" as "Verschiebung" into German. But it is a linguistic term and I did not come across this word in German linguistic sources. I would like to know what is the corresponding term in German lingustics?

> In linguistics, displacement is the capability of language to communicate about things that are not immediately present (spatially or temporally); i.e., things that are either not here or are not here now.

Comment: The "Wikipedia translation method" says [Dislokation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_F._Hockett). I've no idea how accurate that is, or if this term is actually in use in German linguistics.

Answer (score 2):

For the word "displacement" in the sense of Hackett's characterisation of human language, there can be two translations: *Dislokation* or *Dislozierung*. 
It isn't really a fixed term in itself, as *Dislokation* is also used in the context of syntax (in word order: the movement of a word or phrase to another position in the sentence). And *Dislozierung* is also used in the context of morphology.

However, *Dislozierung* appears to be the preferred word in this context.

**Dislozierung über das Hier-und-Jetzt hinaus** is probably the most non-ambiguous translation: https://www.linguistik.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg72/PDF/04_Folie_Hockett_-_Merkmale_menschlicher_Sprache.pdf

https://www.uibk.ac.at/iup/buch_pdfs/9783902936936.pdf

Answer (score 1):

**Dislokation** from https://books.google.com/books?isbn=3110358638 and https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_F._Hockett#Wissenschaftliche_Beitr.C3.A4ge seems fine!

Comment: Dislokation may be fit, by the way I think he means "Kreativität" with "Produktivität"

Comment: This is scarily close to a link-only answer. While the answer in itself may be correct, please include relevant quotes from the sites in your answer here (be sure to cite sources and mark them up as quotations) to prevent link rot.